# aiogram states не могу получить данные

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, state

Всем привет, пишу систему заявок, возникла такая проблема:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=zayavka.answer)
async def first_question_answer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['user_tg_id'] = message.chat.id
        data['answer'] = message.text

    await zayavka.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, zayavka_second_question, parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=zayavka.profile_link)
async def second_question_answer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if not link_checker(message.text):
        if message.text == "none":
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data['profile_link'] = "Нету"

        else:
            return await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, zayavka_question_error, parse_mode='HTML')
    else:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['profile_link'] = message.text

    await zayavka.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, zayavka_third_question, parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=zayavka.answer3)
async def third_question_answer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['answer3'] = message.text

    await zayavka.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, zayavka_fourth_question, parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=zayavka.answer4)
async def all_quesions_show(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['answer4'] = message.text
        await state.finish()

        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, zayavka_all_questions.format(
            answer=data['answer'],
            answer2=data['profile_link'],
            answer3=data['answer3'],
            answer4=data['answer4']), parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=zayavka_info())

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'zayavka_accept')
async def zayavka_accept(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            print(data['user_tg_id'])
            user_id = data['user_tg_id']
            answer = data['answer']
            lolz_link = data['profile_link']
            answer3 = data['answer3']
            answer4 = data['answer4']
```

при нажатии на inline кнопку `zayavka_accept` вызывается функция выше, но выдает такую ошибку:

```
[10.11 13:41:34] Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-39' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=KeyError('user_tg_id')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\proj\Python\zayavki_bot\main.py", line 459, in zayavka_accept
    user_id = data['user_tg_id']
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\storage.py", line 439, in __getitem__
    return self._data[item]
KeyError: 'user_tg_id'
```

Вот весь лог: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMXZo.jpg

Перед этим при заполнении заявки все записывается в стейты и отлично принтится, но в этой функции не работает.

Все стейты:

```
class zayavka(StatesGroup):
    user_tg_id = State()
    answer = State()
    profile_link = State()
    answer3 = State()
    answer4 = State()
```

Вот что показывает при принте стейтов

```
FSMContextProxy state = <default>, data = {}
```

Место записи в стейты:

```
async with state.proxy() as data:
   data['user_tg_id'] = message.chat.id
   data['answer'] = message.text
 await zayavka.next()
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Дайте весь лог ошибки. Хотя догадываюсь что такого значения просто нету в стейте

Comment: @oleksandrigo это и есть весь лог ошибки, добавил стейты

Comment: @oleksandrigo вот скрин консоли: https://imgur.com/a/pbuo7He

Comment: Так уберите `try` он мешает. И после скиньте лог

Comment: А где вы записываете данные в стейт? Типо `data['user_tg_id'] = ...`

Comment: @oleksandrigo да, именно так. Так же было написано в документации по стейтам

Comment: Покажите лог, и место записи в дату

Comment: @oleksandrigo лог чего? ошибки? я добавил уже все что мне выдает лог

Comment: Я же писал, это кривой лог. Уберите try/except и пусть python выдаст нормальную ошибку

Comment: @oleksandrigo добавил!

Comment: @oleksandrigo теперь оно?

Comment: Угу. Так вам же пишет, что в стейте нету такого ключа. Вы часом нигде какого-нибудь `state.finish()` не делали? А лучше киньте весь код

Comment: @oleksandrigo да, нашел. поставил

Comment: @oleksandrigo добавил!

Comment: Ну так само собой, вы удаляете данные, а потом пытаетесь их достать. Сделай удаление позже

Comment: @oleksandrigo если ставить удаление позже, то не работает колбек хендлер который отправляет заявку! вот он: all_quesions_show